# adding an object to an array in for loop. with set and get.

Tags: java, arrays, setter, getter

Im a little confused on adding objects to an array of 7 objects.

I have a for loop and I want to add an item object with 3 arguments. I have used set and get for this. At the end of the for loop, id like to .add item object to the array list. When I try to do this I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at item.add(item.java:88)
>       at homework3main.main(homework3main.java:38)

There are no errors flags on the lines 88 in item class and 38 in main, so I dont know how to correct.

```
   public class item {



public static int x = 0;
public static String setName;
public static double setPrice;
public static int setPrioirty;


public  int priority=-1;
public static double price;
public static String name;
private static item[] list; 



item(){
    this(-1,0, null);
    priority=-1;
    price=0;
    name="No Name yet.";


}// default constructor. 


public item(int i, double j, String k) {
    setitem(i,j,k);//constructor with 3 arguments. 
}

public void setitem (int i, double j, String k){// setting item with 3 attributes.
    setPriority(i);
    setPrice(j);
    setName(k);

}

public void setName(String k) {//setting individual attributes in item.

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub //page 378
    name=k;
    priority=-1;
    price=0;
}


public void setPrice(double j) {//setting individual attributes in item.
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (j<0&&j>100){
        System.out.println("Error: price is too low or high");

    }

    else
        price=j;

    }

public void setPriority(int i) {//setting individual attributes in item.
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    priority =((i>=0&&i<7)?i:0);
    }


public double getPrice(){
    return price;

}
public String getName(){

    return name;

}
public double getPriority(){
    return priority;

}

// eclipse made me create this method when I wanted to "add an itemObject to the list"
 public static void add(item itemObject) {

     System.out.println("Enter an item"+x);
    if (x<7)
    {
        list[x]=itemObject;
    System.out.println("Item added at index " + x);

    x++;
    }








 }

    }
```

---------------------------------main

```
public class homework3main extends item {





public static void main(String[] args) {


    item list[]=new item [7]; // array object
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int x=0; x<list.length;x++){


        item itemObject=new item (setPrioirty,setPrice,setName);
        //creating new object with 3 variables, name, price, priority

        //list[x]=new item();// is this right?
        System.out.println("Enter an item you want to add to your list");
        list[x].setName=keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Enter a price");
        Scanner pricedouble= new Scanner(System.in);
        list[x].setPrice=pricedouble.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the priority of the item");
        Scanner priorityint= new Scanner(System.in);
        list[x].setPrioirty=priorityint.nextInt();

        //item itemObject=new item (setPrioirty,setPrice,setName);

        list[x].add(itemObject);


    }
```

Comment: You have an array but you haven't created its elements, and you are trying to call methods on them.

Comment: Please, follow proper Java naming conventions. Class name should start with uppercase alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` method is the wrong place to initialize an `item`'s array.  Here,

```
item list[]=new item [7];
```

you have declared a local array that is itself called `list`.  Instead, initialize the `list` instance variable of `item` in its constructor or as part of the declaration.

Additionally, I don't see any reason why your class with the `main` method, `homework3main`, should extend `item`.  Plus, the naming convention in Java is to name classes starting with an uppercase character, e.g. `Item` and `Homework3Main`.

Comment: I was just trying different things to get it to work, thats why I put extend item. I didnt think extending item would work in main, but tried it anyway.

Comment: thank you, I added it as static in my Item class and its adding to each index. Extending Item in Main also allowed me to use list in main without creating local variable.